# Is there a maxheap in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, std, standard-library, max-heap

I know the `std::priority_queue` class implements a minheap. Is there a way to use this as a Max heap? Or is there an alternative Maxheap structure? I know I can use the `std::make_heap()` function on a `std::vector` with lambda to create my own Maxheap but then using functions such as `std::pop_heap()` is weird and I don't think they are easy to use. There should be an easier way just like the min_heap(priority queue) I think.

Comment: In the STL, heaps are decoupled from actual container implementations. Have a look at [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap). It lets you pass a custom comparator, in your case that could be `std::greater<>{}`.

Comment: Yes I have been using that but it just felt really weird to use pop_heap() and then pop_back() when Im trying to delete an element so I thought there might be a better alternative. Thank you.

Comment: @lubgr Be aware that `std::make_heap` and all heap algorithms / items in the standard library make max heaps, not min heaps. Thus, `std::greater<>{}` would make a min heap. The easiest way to remember this is to imagine the heap utilities as implementation details for heapsort.

Comment: @Justin good point, I confused the min heap - `std::greater`, max heap - `std::less`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regarding [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> A user-provided `Compare` can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g. using **`std::greater<T>`** would cause the **smallest element** to appear as the `top()`.

Since `std::less<T>` is the default template argument to the `Compare` template parameter, it is already a *max heap* by default. If you want a *min heap* instead (what the quote above suggest), pass `std::greater<T>` instead of `std::less<T>` as the template argument.

To summarize:

- Max Heap: pass `std::less<T>` (this is the default template argument).
- Min Heap: pass `std::greater<T>`.

---

Note that `std::priority_queue` is actually a *container adapter* (in contrast to a data structure). It doesn't specify what underlying data structure is using. However, due to the specified run-time complexity of the operations `push()`, `pop()` and `top()`, it is likely implemented as a heap.

Comment: Then to create a min heap my declaretion would look like ```priority_queue<int, std::greater<int>> q; ``` right?  In the page you linked theres also a vector in the template arguements but I can't understand the reasoning for that.

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar Yes. The vector is the underlying container.

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar you should use
```std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q;```

Comment: Why is `std::less<T>` the template that corresponds to a max heap? Wouldn't `std::greater<T>` make more sense intuitively as the root node with the largest value for data-type `T` has the *greatest* priority?

Comment: @E.Kaufman In the `std::priority_queue`, the "largest" element always comes at the *top*. However, what "largest" means depends on the *comparison function*: It must be defined in such a way so that `true` is returned if its first argument *comes before* (i.e., it is "smaller" than) its second argument. In other words, the comparison function must return `true` if its second argument is "larger" than its first argument – i.e., when `true`, the second argument would become the *top of the heap* before the first argument does. Therefore, if `std::less` is used, the heap corresponds to a max-heap

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html#:~:text=9.1%20Defining%20the%20Comparison%20Function&text=Your%20comparison%20function%20should%20return,first%20argument%20is%20%E2%80%9Cgreater%E2%80%9D.) says "[a comparison fuction] returns positive if the first argument is 'greater'". This doesn't contradict your statement "[a comparison function] must be defined...so that true is returned if its first argument comes before (or 'smaller' than) its second argument". However, I'd be lying if I said I'm not more confused.

Comment: Ok, your definition of "larger" means "is closer the top of the heap". Whereas "smaller" means "is farther from the top of the heap". I think that's what was tripping me up.

Comment: @E.Kaufman exactly. The "largest" is always at the top of the heap. It is then the comparison function that specifies what is considered larger or smaller.

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer**

Max Heap:

```
priority_queue<int> maxHeap; // NOTE: default is max heap
```

Min Heap

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int> , greater<int>> minHeap;
```

Headers and namespaces:

```
#include <vector>
#include <priority_queue>

using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "heap" container just like there is no "search tree", nor "hash map" (instead of latter two, there are ordered and unordered associative containers, which are in practice implemented using those data structures, because no other data structure can satisfy the requirements specified for those containers).

There *is* a container adaptor `std::priority_queue`, which can adapt a SequenceContainer (`std::vector` is adapted by default), and provides same operations as a max/min heap does, and probably internally is implemented as a some kind of heap.

There is also `std::make_heap` which can be used to enforce the max heap property on a random-access range.

Comment: This is really splitting hairs.  The way the standard requires the containers to behave there is really nothing but an RB-Tree that can be used for the associative containers and the unordered containers are required to be a "hash map"/"hash set" (although in a very non-optimal way *bucket iterators*).

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure that no other balanced search tree be used besides RB-tree? There's not necessarily any advantage in using it, but would not AVL tree satisfy all requirements? Regardless, as I said, the associative containers are in practice implemented using those data structures. It's not just splitting hairs though; If the standard did provide a generic tree data structure, then it should be augmentable to implement different kinds of trees. But it doesn't; It provides an associative container with interface that is implementable using a tree instead.