# Does c++ boost library has a big top heap implementation?

Tags: c++, boost

c++ boost has a big top heap implementation?how can i use it?or how can i use c++ boost implements a priority_queue?i have no idea now.i have used stl::priority_queue,but it do not meet my requirement. If I push 5 elements into a c++ priority_queue，then pop（） elements，i want memory space of queue will be release

Comment: What's a "big top heap"? I've never heard of such a thing. Anyway, boost's heap implementations: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/heap.html

Comment: `std::prioty_queue` uses `std::vector` to store element by default and that has a `shrink_to_fit` method

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "big top heap" you mean a max heap: `std::priority_queue` is a min heap by default, but you [can make it into a max-heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271271/is-there-a-maxheap-in-the-c-standard-library) by giving it a different comparator.

`std::priority_queue` itself isn't in charge of it memory allocations; that's handled by the underlying container. By default, that is `std::vector`, which doesn't free any memory when it shrinks. But you can create your own wrapper around `std::vector` which calls [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) at appropriate times.

Note that there is *usually* no reason to do this. The memory is freed when the heap is destroyed. But if it's long-lived, usually small, but occasionally big enough to cause memory pressure on the system, then this technique might be needed.

Comment: Switching to ```std::priority_queue<T, std::deque<T>, std::greater<T> >``` would also deallocate most memory.